# База данных для чата ms sql

Tags: c#, sql

Хочу создать базу данных для чата. В курсе что для этого нужно создать таблицу с пользователями и сообщениями. Но чем заполнять эти таблицы, какой код нужно вводить? Подскажите пожалуйста направление

Answer (score 1):

Начну с того, что чат для базы данных - это не правильно, нужно либо ноsql, либо какое-то простенькое логирование.
Базы данных это не для мгновенного обмена сообщениями, погуглите, почему это плохо.

Но в плане развития, напишу как бы это могло быть сделано:
Существует много вариантов для получения данных из базы.
Например стандартный SqlConnection (Гайды можете найти на msdn или среди ответов по тем же тегам, что написали, тут таких вопросов больше 100 было)

Я советую использовать Dapper, чтобы было хорошее понимание, как sql, но уже не писать кучу лишнего кода.

Ещё вариант использовать Entity Framework.

Прежде всего подключитесь к sql серверу и создайте необходимые таблицы. Не скупитесь на справочники и верную архитектуру(Стоит почитать про архитектурные решения для чатов).

create table команда, которая создаст таблицу, как её использовать тоже на msdn. Вам надо создать справочник юзеров, и саму таблицу для мессагей, например (Код не проверяю, считайте его псевдокодом и тем куда надо копать)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Users DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR datetime


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Messages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Messages] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Messages DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR datetime
```

грубый код для c# с использованием чистого sql connection будет приблизительно такой:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("коннекшн к базе данных, который можно получить создав файлик udl на рабочем столе, настроить его, а потом открыть блокнотом"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Строка того, что вы хотите сделать в базе, например insert into ChatMessage @message,@userID", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", "сообщение из переменной где устроен у вас чат");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", "айди юзера");

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Если нужно просто залогировать всё из чатов в sql, а не строить чат на основе SQL. То стоит юзать какую-нибудь систему очередей MQ, для того, чтобы сообщения улетали в MQ, а чат не тормозил, а MQ в своем темпе складовала всё в БД.